# Save push notification into CoreData while app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I have push notifications in my app. While in app it's very easy to grab notification and store some data  from it into CoreData. Not so much when the app is not running. This is a messaging app so I want to be able to quickly store messages that are delivered to the user while app is not running.

I get very inconsistent results by using background mode with content-available flag on. Sometimes content gets stored right away other times there is nothing.

What is the best way to handle this type of system?

Comment: Hey, ever found a solution to this problem?